# Raspberry Pi Google Assistant: googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk command saying no config found

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I'm making a google assistant with my Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm just trying make an LED turn on and off like in the docs (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/handle-device-commands) but when I run this command `googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk` to test it, I get an error:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples- 
 assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device 
instance.
```

I've tried troubleshooting but nothing seems to work. I'm completely lost here. Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I just needed to add the device model id and the project id to the end of the command so it could register.

`googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --device-model-id <device model id> --project-id <project id>`

I hope this helps others!